# Create a callback that returns a value to its caller?

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, callback

I am creating a class ("Class B") which is used by another class ("Class A") which instantiates it in VB.NET 3.5.

I would like `Class B` to read a value assigned to one of its properties by `Class A` every time an event happens in `Class B`.

However, I would like this property value to be dynamically assigned to the property by `Class A` when the event is fired in `Class B`.

I was thinking about somehow creating a delegate function in `Class A` that is linked to the property in `Class B` so that when the event is fired in `Class B` it would eventually invoke the delegate in `Class A` so that it returns a value to `Class B`.

I've been reading around delegates (that's how I arrived at the idea), but I am stuck on how to code this up - could someone please help with some skeleton code?

Also, I am not sure that this is the best approach for this - are there better solutions?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Are you referring to something similar to, say, the form onClosing event where you can alter the EventArgs to cancel the closure?

Comment: That could also be a possible route, and I would be interested in how I could implement something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably isolate this from both classes a little. Maybe create a singleton that creates the value from Class A  and just call that from Class B.

So

```
Public Class MySingleton

   'Singleton related code here

   Public Property MyDynamicValue As Integer

End Class
```

Then in Class A

```
Public Sub HandleClassBEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ClassB.MyEvent
   MySingleTonInstance.MyDynamicValue = SetMyDynamicValue()
End sub
```

In Class B

```
   Public ReadOnly Property MyValueFromClassA Integer
      Get
           MySingletonInstance.MyDynamicValue
      End Get
   End Property
```